# Return a array/list using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I would like to return a array `string[]` or a list `List<string>` using `regex`.

I want to compare a `string` and return all values that starts with `[` and end with `]`.

I am new to `regex`, so would you please explain the syntax that you will be using to produce the right results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[([^\[\]]*)\]")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

This regex `\[([^\[\]]*)\]` means:

1. `\[` - character `[`
2. `([^\[\]]*)` - any character, excluding `[]` any number of repetitions, group 1
3. `\]` - character `]`

**Update**:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[[^\[\]]*\]")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string pattern = Regex.Escape("[") + "(.*?)]";
string input = "Test [Test2] .. sample text [Test3] ";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
var myResultList = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    myResultList.Add(match.Value);
}
```

The result list would contain : [Test2], [Test3]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Say i want to change the last `]` to `?]`, how would i do that, so that it will return `[Test2?]`?

Comment: Does your source string contain the word `'Test2?'`..  ??

Comment: Yes... So how will i set the ending characters?

Comment: Yes, you can escape it by adding a preceding `'\'`.

Answer (score 1):

Stallman says : "When you want to solve a problem using regexp, now you have two problems".

In your case it's something like ^\[.*\]$

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1