# Tidy up a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for the best solution, performance wise, to rebuild a string by removing words that are not complete words. An acceptable word in this instance is a whole word without numbers or doesn't start with a forward slash, or a back slash. So just letters only, but can include hyphen and apostrophe's

For example:

`String str ="\DR1234 this is a word, 123456, frank's place DA123 SW1 :50:/"`

Using the above I'd need a new string that returns the following:

`Str = "this is a word, frank's place"`

I've done some research on `Regex`, but I can't find anything that would do what I need.

**Final Code Snippet**

```
var resultSet = Regex.Matches(item.ToLower(), @"(?:^|\s)(?![\\\/])(?!-+(?:\s|$))(?!'+(?:\s|$))(?!(?:[a-z'-]*?-){3,})(?!(?:[a-z'-]*?'){2,})[a-z'-]+[,.]?(?=\s|$)")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Thanks for all your input guys - proves what a great site this is

Comment: How do you decide on appropriate punctuation vs inappropriate?  'word, 123456, frank' removes the obvious numbers which are not a word but you have two comma's and only one is kept in your output.

Comment: Define "words" first. Only valid (in the dictionary), grammatically correct text? Or any clumps of English characters?

Comment: Regex is dumb in this respect. It doesn't know what a "word" is. In regex, \w is word, but even this doesn't completely solve your problem.

Comment: I would consider splitting on spaces then check each word, keeping only valid words. Your example suggests that punctuation would be kept at the end of a word, also that `'s` is OK at a word end. But the question is too vague about what is a word to give a good answer,

Comment: A word in this instance is a whole word without numbers or doesn't start with a forward slash, or a back slash. So just letters only, but can include hyphen and apostrophe's

Comment: I'm writing a validation program that needs to accept a persons name, company name or country - so Frank Smith would be a name, Microsoft would be a company and Brazil would be the country. I then make an Webservice call to a sanctions list returning a match or not.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want a character class like `\w` that matches non-ASCII letters but not numbers or `_`, try `[^\W\d_]` (with appropriate settings to make sure `\w` matches whatever non-ASCII characters you're after)

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: Should "gr8 question" produce "question"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Description

Based on your comments: `A word in this instance is:`

```
a whole word without numbers 
doesn't start with a forward slash, or a back slash
just letters only
can include hyphen and apostrophes
```

The character class to cover all the word characters by your definition would be `[a-z'-]+` and that group could be surrounded by whitespace, or the start/end of a string. You sample also shows a comma so I'm presuming a word can be followed by a comma or dot either of which are followed by white space is ok too.

This regex will:

- collect all substings defined as words `[a-z'-]+`
- allow a comma or dot after a word, but not inside or at the start of a word
- rejects substrings from containing all hyphens
- rejects substrings from containing all apostrophes
- prevents words from having 3 or more hyphens
- prevents words from having 2 or more apostrophes

`(?:^|\s)(?![\\\/])(?!-+(?:\s|$))(?!'+(?:\s|$))(?!(?:[a-z'-]*?-){3,})(?!(?:[a-z'-]*?'){2,})[a-z'-]+[,.]?(?=\s|$)`

[image]

## Expanded explanation

- `(?:^|\s)` match the start of the string or a white space. This eliminates the need to test for word boundary which is problematic for strings like "abdc-egfh"
- `(?![\\\/])` prevent the word from starting with a \ or /, however this is over kill as the character class doesn't allow it either
- `(?!-+(?:\s|$))` prevent strings which are all hyphens
- `(?!'+(?:\s|$))` prevent strings which are all apostrophes
- `(?!(?:[a-z'-]*?-){3,})` prevent strings which have 3 or more hyphens
- `(?!(?:[a-z'-]*?'){2,})` prevent strings which have 2 or more apostrophes
- `[a-z'-]+[,.]?(?=\s|$)` match the word followed by some optional punctuation, and ensure this is followed by either a space or the end of a string

## Examples

I'm not a C# programmer, but a returned array of matches from a code block like the one covered in question [Return a array/list using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417206/return-a-array-list-using-regex) and this regular expression will probably work for you. Note this expression does assume you'll use the case insensitive option.

**Sample Text**

```
\DR1234 - this is a word, 123456, frank's place DA123 SW1 :50:/  one-hyphen two-hyphens-here I-have-three-hyphens
```

**Matches**

```
[0] =>  this
[1] =>  is
[2] =>  a
[3] =>  word,
[4] =>  frank's
[5] =>  place
[6] =>  one-hyphen
[7] =>  two-hyphens-here
```

Comment: Hi Denomales, first off thanks for the detailed explanation. I ran your rege through Rubular, and it produced the following: http://rubular.com/r/mV2aTghkHU

Comment: What is your tool to generate the regex?

Comment: Hey Daniel, I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds, named capture groups, or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Answer (score 1):

the regex:  `\b\w+\b` will match words  or if you're more picky, than `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b` won't include numbers or `_`s

http://rubular.com/r/uOVvPTb5nh

---

It looks like you want to allow `'`s and `,`s, so the regex: `\b[a-zA-Z,']+\b` will do an okay job at that, but it will also let slip through any number of things that you might not want(such as

```
,','hello''',World
```

---

or, in c#,

```
string str =@"\DR1234 this is a word, 123456, frank's place DA123 SW1 :50:/";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b[a-zA-Z,']+\b");

string newStr = string.Join(" ", r.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray());
```

Comment: You can also add your allowed punctuation like so: \b[a-zA-Z']+\b

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'll do some testing in the morning.

Comment: The problem with `\b[a-zA-Z,']+\b` is that you don't know whether the first and last characters are going to be word characters, which somewhat confuses things when you're using word boundary. For instance, consider the string `the Jones' car`. Since `'` is a non-word character, there's a word boundary before it, not after it; so the second matched substring will be `Jones`, not `Jones'`.

Comment: David, the engine that i send the string (word) to be validated normalizes the input, so this would be fine. But, thanks for taking the time to point this out

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Match("[a-z\s,']+")` is what you're looking for.  So here is the code example:

```
string pattern = "[a-z\s,']+";
string input = @"\DR1234 this is a word, 123456, frank's place DA123 SW1 :50:/";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
while (match.Success){
   Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
   match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Igor, this would allow 123456, to be included.

Comment: Why have you included `\b`? Inside a character class, `\b` is not a word boundary, but rather a backspace character, in keeping with standard backslash-escaping in string literals. In fact, a word boundary doesn't even make sense inside a character class, since a character class must match exactly one character (substring of length 1) and word boundary is a zero-width assertion (substring of length 0). Another problem is that there are 2 levels of escaping, one for the string literal and one for the regex, which also makes it a backspace. Sam I Am's answer is closer, but also problematic IMO.

Comment: ups my mistake, It was supposed to represent a blank space. thx!

Comment: @CSharpNewBee Nop it wouldn't since we are not including [0-9].

Comment: Igor, :50:test1 would be identified as test using the above. If any combination of a word contains a numeric then is should be ignore.